# My Room Light Switch doesn't seem to be grounded, while everything else is

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I pulled the cover off of my light switches in my room, and found that the ground screw had no wire connected to it, the switch is in a metal box, and the wires are fed through the holes in the back. The second switch does absolutely nothing. What does this mean? Are they supposed to be like this? My house was built in 1950, but most of the electrical stuff was redone in 2022 except what is in the basement (all ungrounded). All of the newer outlets are connected with ground wire, but this neither the light switch
nor the metal box were connected to a ground wire.

Comment: Is it possible that box is connected with wires in conduit instead of cable?  Metal screws plus metal box plus metal conduit will be ground.  While having ground is good, most switches can be safe without it.   Newer code does allow separate ground wire to be added to circuit to next ground point.

Comment: If armored cable is bringing the power into the box, the box may be grounded. You can check with a multimeter. In which case you can run a ground from the switch to the box. If there are wires attached to the other switch, it might be powering a switched outlet in the room.

Comment: A picture of what you're seeing will help us determine if it's OK or not

Answer (score 2):

Two separate issues:

- Metal Box

A metal box can be grounded in one of two ways. If it is used with cables then the ground wire in the cable should be attached to a screw in the box. If it is used with metal conduit and individual wires then if there is no separate ground wire (not needed with metal conduit) then the conduit itself provides the ground and nothing extra is needed.

- Switch

A switch in a metal box does not need a ground wire attached to the switch! The screw is there for switches installed in plastic boxes. As long as the switch is installed properly, the yoke of the switch grounds to the box and the box is grounded as noted above.

Comment: Well, the wires in the older, not redone portion of the house is all stuffed in wiremold, but in the other portion of the house, it's all in some yellow cables run around the house. The screw inside the metal box is not connected to a wire

Comment: @JaeWieg  Yellow cable should be modern 12 gauge cable.  Usually has a ground wire.  Possible the ground was not connected by mistake.  Even professionals have oops moments.

Comment: Also check if ground connected on outside of box - I have found that on some boxes in my house.